# Why is axios POST is called twice?

Tags: reactjs, axios, express-router

My react app uses axios for POST-requests to the server. When the server needs more than 2min for answering the request is called again.
But only in FF, Chrome, NOT in IE11.
I don't think that this is a Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) preflight issue, because this happens only for requests with long response times.

```
Client:
    axios.post("host:port/context", {
      params,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain"
      }
    });

Server:
const server = http.createServer();
server.listen(4000);
server.setTimeout(240000);
server.keepAliveTimeout = 240000;

A Router from express is also used on the server:
const router = new Router();
router.post(
  "/context",
  handlingOfRequest()
);
```

Comment: it sounds like an issue with browser's native ajax call timeout value. You might want to check  XMLHttpRequest.timeout

Comment: The try by making the ajax call with XHR and timeout (and not via axios) ends with the same result. The request is called twice.

Comment: const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
    xhr.timeout = 480000;
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(e);
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          console.log(e);
        } else {
          console.error(xhr.statusText);
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function(e) {
      console.error(xhr.statusText);
    };

Comment: It's not an OPTIONS request right? It's POST

Comment: Yes it's a POST ...

Comment: dev7005 Have you ever found a solution to this? Having the same problem